# Why is onListItemClick reporting the wrong position?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sdk-tools

I've overridden `onListItemClick` in `ListFragment` to get the selected item.

The function works great the first time I open the fragment.  But after I navigate to some different activities and return via the back button or `finish()`, the position reported is wrong.  Do I need to do something to reset this fragment after it's returned to?

**onListItemClick:**

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Brewery brewery = ((BreweryAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);

    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onBrewerySelected(brewery);
    }
}
```

My `BreweryAdapter` is very simple- it just populates the view pieces with their data.

Any ideas?  My code matches the examples I've looked at online.  Thanks!

Comment: Does the underlying dataset change while you're not on the fragment in question? and by how much is the position off when you come back?

Comment: Have you checked any changes in List of Brewery?

Comment: You could try to refresh your ListView when you come to your fragment using `((BreweryAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();` just to check if it contains invalid data

Comment: zozelfelfo's suggestion does fix the issue.  I am still concerned about what the source is though, since I've set breakpoints and am confident my data isn't being changed between activities.  Could anything else explain the problem?  The positions are usually off by 1 (1 greater than my selection).  Thanks!